# C++: initial a pointer

Tags: c++, pointers

These codes are parts of project:

//.h file

```
#ifndef IMAGEFILTER_H
#define IMAGEFILTER_H

#include "filter.h"

class ImageFilter : public Filter {
public:
    ImageFilter(int _dimension);
    virtual ~ImageFilter();
protected:
    int* values;
};
#endif // IMAGEFILTER_H
```

//.cpp file

```
#include "imagefilter.h"

ImageFilter::ImageFilter(int _d) : Filter(_d) {
    values = new int[_d * _d];
}

ImageFilter::~ImageFilter() {
    delete [] values;
}
```

How should I understand the line :"values = new int[_d * _d];" ?
Could you help me ?

Comment: Probably as a pointer to a heap-allocated buffer of `_d * _d *sizeof(int)` bytes. Or yes, undefined behavior if this is not an excerpt but the full code.

Comment: Sorry, my friends, I should post all relative codes just now. I have edited my question.@songyuanyao@Marco A@songyuanyao

Comment: I'd say that your filter stores a two-dimensional image of quadratic shape with a side length of _d that is stored in an array over int, accessed by something like "coordinates x,y are stored at position x + _d*y" (or the other way around - in any case, it's somewhat strange that _d is not stored itself). The line in question initializes the array. Everything clear now? Btw, in C++, one would prefer std::vector over an array whenever possible.

Comment: I think you need a [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: I took `*` as the symbol of the pointer just now, in fact, it means multiplying. Many thanks for your answer.@Aziuth

Comment: Gratitude also for you! @molbdnilo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does `values = new int[_d * _d];` mean?

Reserve `_d * _d` of sequenced integers (probably 4 byte each) dynamically in the free store. In other words, you have reserved an array of `integers` with `_d * _d` items that can be used later in many ways.

Comment: You are trying to do image processing in C++ while you do not even know what dynamic arrays are.. probably you need to start from a lower level and find some good C++ book (with absolutely no offense). and  I have answered your question already.

Comment: Glad for you timely reply! I absolutely agree with your words, also I am a green bird. I took `*` as the symbol of the pointer just now, in fact, it means multiplying. Thank for your advice very much!